# Is there a theme for sublime that is close to the default look of Webmatrix?

Tags: themes, sublimetext2, webmatrix, sublimetext3

I absolutely love sublime text, loves coding on it, but i adore the simple and neat default theme of webmatrix. I just love it's UI, 
Does anyone know a Sublime text theme that is similar to webmatrix? 
The closest themes i could find were variations of the mac classic theme bundled with sublime text.

Answer (score 1):

Browse through the [color schemes](https://sublime.wbond.net/browse/labels/color%20scheme) on Package Control. There are a lot, but you should be able to find something you like.

BTW, from the [Help Center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic):

> Questions asking us to recommend or find a tool, library or favorite off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam.

Answer (score 1):

There is a colour scheme called 'Vintage Terminal'.

search for that in https://packagecontrol.io/browse/labels/color%20scheme

It downloads various vintage terminal colours

Answer (score 0):

Hi to those coming there 3 years later, like I just did an hour ago, here is a pretty good retro pirat terminal matrix color sheme: 
http://colorsublime.com/theme/ILMHackers:

[image: ILMHackers for sublme text]

Comment: Getting a access forbidden on that page now; "You don't have permission to access /theme/ILMHackers on this server."

Comment: Right, found it on github: https://github.com/warmwaffles/sublime-settings/blob/master/Colorsublime%20-%20Themes/cache/Colorsublime-Themes-master/themes/ILMHackers.tmTheme